# How to fill in radio button with iTextSharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, pdf, itext

I have a radio group which I am trying to fill using `iTextSharp` library. When I opened the PDF in `iText RUPS` I see the following:

[image]

This is how it is in the PDF file:

[image]

I have the following code-behind which is supposed to populate either MALE or FEMALE radio button:

```
if (reader.GetValue(4).ToString() == "M")
                        {
                            pdfFormFields.SetField("SEXpg2", "Yes");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            pdfFormFields.SetField("SEXpg2", "Yes");
                        }
```

When I run the PDF form, none of the radio is populated. How can I modify the code from the screenshot so it populates either radio based on the gender column from the sql query?

I tried the following but that didn't work:

```
if (reader.GetValue(4).ToString() == "M")
                        {
                            pdfFormFields.SetField("MALEpg2", "Yes");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            pdfFormFields.SetField("FEMALEpg2", "Yes");
                        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*+1 for using iText RUPS!*

You should be able to do:

```
pdfFormFields.SetField("SEXpg2", "MALEpg2");
```

and

```
pdfFormFields.SetField("SEXpg2", "FEMALEpg2");
```

Comment: PERFECT... I was going to try but don't recall the reason why I didn't!!! Silly me... Thanks!